# Getting user token just using the email on server side (Firebase)

Tags: android, email, firebase, server, token

My question is this: I´m trying to send a push notification to a group of devices, I have a node of all the users and their current Firebase tokens. 
When a user sends a message to a group of devices, I read each value of each user email and get each token, then proceed to send for each token a message.

I know that Firebase provide a method for susbcriptions, the thing is that is not a good idea to use that because maybe the users don´t want to be susbribed to the specific topic of the message.

I know that there´s a method on the server where I get the user´s email by getting their user token, is there a way to use it the other way around (getting the user token using the email)?